# TFS Feedback Url is incorrect (mfbclient)

Tags: tfs

When I request feedback in TFS the email that is sent generates a URL:

mfbclient://tfs.ourserver.com:8443/tfs/DefaultCollection/p:OurProject?rid=2717%2c2718

When I click on the link I get:

[image: ConnectionError]

But if I change the url to be:

mfbclients://tfs.ourserver.com:8443/tfs/DefaultCollection/p:OurProject?rid=2717%2c2718

It works perfectly! (changed mfbclient to mfbclients)

**So, is there a setting or something, somewhere in TFS that I need to change to get the generated emails to have the correct URL? And if so where exactly?**

Note: This is on premise TFS (not sure if that makes a difference)

Answer (score 0):

By default, on-premise TFS generates a mfbclient:// url, and it works. But it seems your TFS has been set up HTTPS with SSL, so when you configure an SMTP server, try to select the second checkbox and enter a certificate:

[image]